# executing python in the command line inside a controller - PHP/CodeIgniter

Tags: php, python, codeigniter

Inside my `automation.php` controller, I have the following function:

```
public function deploy_test() {

      echo json_encode(system("python --version"));
 }
```

When the user wants to deploy a test, by clicking a `test` button in the webpage, he would be able to accomplish such a task.
However, when I click the `test` button, my output is:

```
""
```

Meanwhile, when I execute the same function with the command:

```
public function deploy_test() {

    echo json_encode(system("ls -l"));
}
```

I'm getting:

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x. 15 philippe philippe 4096 Mar  4 16:48 application
drwxrwxr-x.  2 philippe philippe 4096 Mar  4 17:28 css
-rw-r--r--.  1 philippe philippe 6357 Jan 30 11:53 index.php
drwxrwxr-x.  2 philippe philippe 4096 Feb 27 15:38 js
-rw-r--r--.  1 philippe philippe 2496 Jan 30 11:53 license.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  8 philippe philippe 4096 Jan 30 11:53 system
drwxr-xr-x. 12 philippe philippe 4096 Jan 30 11:53 user_guide
```

Could someone please help me to get that straighten out?

Comment: does the python command work when typed directly into the command line?

Comment: @Jeemusu It does, and it also works when I execute the command above from a simple `test.php` file.

Comment: Are the test.php and codeigniter code being run on the same server?

Comment: @Jeemusu Yes, they are

Comment: what does `python -c "print(1); exit(10)"` and `env python --version` do?

Comment: Check if the user/group from the webserver has permissions to execute python commands. Also try using the full path for python. It shouldn't be a limitation of CodeIgniter, but I'll try to test something and comment again. Good luck with that.

Comment: echo json_encode(shell_exec("python --version")); or echo json_encode(exec("python --version")); What does that give you?  One of those should return the json encoded output.

Comment: It's a user/group permission problem. I tried it in CI and executing it from the commandline works, but from the browser doesn't because it's a different user who isn't allowed to execute python from the commandline

Answer (score 4):

The problem is **not** with your code or PHP.

The problem is with your permissions.

php uses permissions which are set in the env-vars of apache.

Which is ideally set as :

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

under your apache2 / httpd conf file.

For example:

Try running:

```
<?= `whoami` ?>
```

via your shell and via your browser.

Your browser will probably say www-data and shell will say your username or if you are on AWS - default, you would get `root`

You do not have to use `system()` , use `exec()` instead.

We should be close as :

```
echo json_encode(exec("python --version"));
```

Performing operations will require you to have correct User and Groups set.

Look up for : [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21)

So your code should be :

```
echo json_encode(exec("python --version 2>&1"));
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for my production server

```
public function deploy_test() {
    echo json_encode(system("python --version 2>&1"));
}
```

with the output

```
Python 2.7.3
"Python 2.7.3"
```

Output of the unix command printed twice as system() itself outputs the result to browser. So exec() can be used in the place of system to avoid this.

```
public function deploy_test() {
    echo json_encode(exec("python --version 2>&1"));
}
```

which outputs

```
"Python 2.7.3"
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is not in the path. Try:

Type the full path to the python command (such as `/usr/bin/python --version`)

1. Find out with the command which, 'which python'
2. try executing your script from the command line, 'php script.php' => sometimes the web
       server sets up things differently
3. make sure the error displaying is enabled with

   ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: a couple of things: I created a mock `test.php` file, and I executed the program, and it worked as supposed. Then when I executed my `script.py` the results were the expected. The problem appears to be when I try to execute it from `codeigniter`.

Answer (score 0):

system returns only last line.
[system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

```
public function deploy_test() {

      system("python --version", $out);
      echo json_encode(implode($out));
 }
```

Comment: it returns `0` only. and `$out` needs to be an array in order to work with `implode` ( it is not ).

Comment: Sorry. Python -v returns output into second stream. You have to use $retval = exec("/usr/bin/python --version 2>&1", $out); 
var_dump($retval);

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of hack, but you can find out the version number with 1 decimal even if you aren't allowed to execute python (which is the case with the 'user' CI).

```
//find python path
exec("which python", $path);

//show all subdirs in python    
exec("ls -l ".$path[0]."*", $output);
$output = implode("\n", $output);

//preg match on version numbers    
preg_match_all("#python(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)#", $output , $matches);
$installed_versions = $matches[1];

//sort in reversing order
$versions_sorted_desc = array_reverse($installed_versions);

//latest version is element 0
$latest_version = $versions_sorted_desc[0];

echo $latest_version;
```